# iOS image size of retina image from web service

Tags: ios, image, web-services

Suppose I want an image to be 320x100 points for a retina screen, I would have to make an image 640x200 pixel and named it @2x. The problem is when I download an image from a web service of size 640x200 pixel. Normally a @2x image would be translate to size 320x100 points in the phone, but the image from the web service is still 640x200 points.

Note - the web service is my own, so I can fix it if it's the web service's problem.

Sorry If might have not worded the problem well, but this is what I meant(similar):
[Retina display and [UIImage initWithData]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289286/retina-display-and-uiimage-initwithdata)

Comment: First of all you should establish a general measurement unit. Don't use points and pixels because you will get confused and 1 point is not equal with 2 pixels.

Comment: Use `+[imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]` with scale=2

Comment: @danypata Then what should I use to reference size in the device? My understanding is that for a retina device 1x1 point == 2x2 pixels

Comment: You should use pixels for measurements. It's more precise and like this you can avoid errors (splitting one pixel in half)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set the height and width of the control in points manually and it will automatically display the image with a higher DPI without unnecesarily downscaling.

Comment: Or more precisely: `UIImage * img = ...;
img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:2 orientation:img.imageOrientation];` (For others who have the same problem)

Comment: But all devices don't have a scale of 2. That's why you must set it to the intended height and width, or dynamically calculate the correct scale at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

An @2x image will always be twice the dimensions of a non-retina image if it wasn't loaded through imageNamed.

Create an image like so on a retina and non-retina device:

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"anImageName"];
NSLog(@"%@: scale: %f", NSStringFromCGSize(anImage.size), anImage.scale);
```

The CGSize object printed on the retina device will be the same size of the non-retina image, but will have the scale set to 2.0.

Creating an image using the explicit retina suffix will reveal that the image is actually twice as big - so imageNamed does its own image scaling.

For the case where you want to display this in an already created and sized image view, you still don't need to do anything - just load it straight in and the image view will adjust the image to the correct size.

If, however, you want to create a new image view, then you'll need to create a frame paying attention to the UIScreen's resolution like so (unfortunately, you can't just set the scale property as its read only):

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectZero;
newFrame.size.width = (anImage.size.width / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
newFrame.size.height = (anImage.size.height / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

This assumes that your web service is aware of wether the screen of the device is retina or not; some services will pick this up automatically, some will require you to tell them this up front. YMMV.

Comment: I have tried logging the size of the image and have found that if I put @2x in `[UIImage imageNamed:]` then I will get the real pixel resolution. However, if I did not include it, I will get the halved resolution in point system. I have read that I should not include @2x because iOS will decide on its own whether the device is retina or not and load an appropriate image. So in the "device" shouldn't the size of a non retina and retina be the same (albeit with different scale)?

Comment: Hmm ... it seems that iOS is already scaling the image down in the imageNamed: implementation. I've reproduced this with the simulator. Odd ...

Comment: I have checked and `@2x` image without explicit `@2x` in `imageNamed:` has its scale automatically set to 2.0.

Comment: Interesting - +[UIImage imageNamed:] is returning a half-sized image, but with the scale set to 2.0 instead of 1.0. So its definitely getting the right image. I'll update the answer above accordingly.